# How to simulate the status bar in Codename one?

Tags: notifications, simulation, codenameone, statusbar

I am currently trying to get a local notification to work on an example app. I was following the simple guide here and just copied its code to see it working:

https://github.com/codenameone/codenameone-demos/blob/master/LocalNotificationTest/src/com/codename1/tests/localnotifications/LocalNotificationTest.java

However, in the simulation, I cannot see any changes in the status bar. Is the status bar even simulated or just a static image? Do I have to build the app and send it to an actual device every time I want to test it? That would not only be tedious but also crunch on the available monthly builds.
Is there a setting in the simulator to activate this that I missed?

Thanks and best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local notifications happen in the background which isn't supported by the simulator so this is something you will only see on the device. You can simulate the minimizing of the app (pause/resume) but the Codename One simulator is not a full mobile OS simulator.